# Dynamic Binary Search

Tags: arrays, sorting, binary, dynamic-data

Note that I do not want any code for this problem, just any references or
help about how this data structure really works so that I can do
my task.

I want to execute the operations for finding and inserting a value in a set
of n numbers. The whole point is to use dynamic binary search, and use
more than one sorted arrays.Let's say `k=[log(n+1)]` and `<n(k-1),n(k-2),...,n(0)>`
is the binary representation of `n`. We have `k` sorted arrays

```
A(0),A(1),...,A(k-1)
```

where for `i=0,1,...k-1` of each `A(i)`, the size of each array is `2^i`.

Each array is full or empty whether `n(i)=1` or `n(i)=0`.
Although each array is sorted, there is not any relation between
elements in different arrays.

If anyone has a clue about this, could you help me?

Again, I only want more info about this data structure, any links
or references that could help me. I don't want any code.

Comment: If there is no relationship between the different arrays, surely you have no choice but to search each array in turn?

Comment: Yes,there is no relationship between elements in different arrays.
I guess so..

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a problem taken from the chapter on amortized analysis from CLRS.  Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some suggested reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree